# How to make drag drop tree in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need some drap&drop tree plugin like [this](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/) for Django Admin.
Anybody knows about such plugins for Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for it I found [this one](https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable) (never used though). It's not very clear what you need, maybe if you explain it a little better people could give you the right path to follow.

Besides that, it is always possible to customize Django Admin (override or extend) templates as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates). By using this approach you could implement everything by yourself (using jQuery UI or Bootstrap for example).

Good luck!